# Blazor app is very slow on azure static web app

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I deployed my Blazor WASM app to azure static web site. When I open the web site it is very slow in the first time. I was able only open it from my PC. On mobile and tablet it is not even opening the page.

I am deploying it with github action as in documentation of azure static web app. The location of resource is East asia (close to me). I checked the the size of output, It is about 19 mb, but I don't think that is a problem, because empty blazor app size is 15mb.

Does anyone faced with this problem? I research, but couldn't find any solution

Comment: Have you checked the network connectivity ?

Comment: Try to check with the Central US location once.

Comment: Iam able to access the app in both `Central US` and `East Asia` without any issues.

Comment: Does it work the same on the localhost? 
I've recently deployed a Blazor WASM site to Azure Static Web App and I haven't noticed any differences between a localhost and a deployed site.

Maybe you deployed the app in debug config and the assemblies are not optimized?

Comment: Yes working in both localhost and in azure.

Comment: I have the same problems. Loading a simple text file with just one two digit number takes over 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Blazor WASM, there will be an initial *cold start* delay as your application runtime is downloaded to the client. From there, if you are not making any server-side or API calls, then any performance issues will be directly in the client's browser, and should not depend on the host. For this reason it can be very economical to host multiple blazor WASM applications from a single low resourced App Service.

So the hosting should have negligible affect outside of the initial *cold start*.

19mb is tiny for Blazor, this indicates that the dependencies might not be included in the deployment, please check your hosting model configuration.

Without more information or code, we can only really speculate, but what code is running during your initialization of the application? Have you created an infinite loop or are you making a call to another API that might be blocked? Are you trying to render too many components to the screen...